# Access files of a debian package from postinst script

Tags: apt, dpkg

Is it possible, to access the files of a Debian-package from its `postinst` script?

Usually, I would use something like `dpkg -c path/to/deb`, but calling `apt`/`dpkg` inside a `postinst` script isn't possible, right?

Currently, I install the package using `dpkg -i path/to/deb`, later the package shall be offered by a repository.

What I am trying to achieve:

```
dpkg -i myPackage_1.0-0_all.deb
```

unpacks files (especially *.specialTag)

`postinst` runs a script, which works with all the `*.specialTag` files **on the system** (using `find / -name *.specialTag`).

That works fine if there are no old `*.specialTag` files on the system, because:

- If I remove a `*.specialTag` file from `myPackage_1.0-0_all.deb`, create a new version `myPackage_1.0-1_all.deb` and install it, then the `*.specialTag` file is still on the system.
- My `postinst` script will find it and work with it.

So what I have in mind is not to loop through all files on the system, but only through those I bring with me in `myPackage_1.0-1_all.deb`

But then I need to call `dpkg`/`apt` inside the `postinst` script.

Answer (score 6):

To get the list of files installed by a package you can use `dpkg -L YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME`, and this works as you'd expect during `postinst`. (So if your package is named `example` the command is `dpkg -L example`.)

`dpkg -L` seems to work even when the `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` lockfile is locked, and in any case the lock is *not* held during `postinst`.

You can also use the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME.list`, which `dpkg` creates during the install of the package before running its `postinst`. (So if your package is named `example` the file is `/var/lib/dpkg/info/example.list`.)

Both of the above give a list of all files (and all parent directories up to the root, which you may need to filter out depending on what you're doing) that are contained within the package.

Comment: +1 And the package name is available as `$DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE` during the script execution if you don't want to hard-code it.

Comment: Are you sure about `dpkg -L`? AFAIK querying the file list like that doesn't need locking the database, and a quick test seems to work fine.

Comment: @muru I remember when I ran `dpkg -L` with `strace` (tracking forked child processes too) and searched the output I saw that it did indeed open the `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` file and then called `flock` on the resultant file descriptor.

Comment: @mtraceur I see. Perhaps you can test running `dpkg -L` in a postinst? Maybe dpkg simply tries to lock, but doesn't fail if it couldn't for query commands.

Comment: @muru You're right, I just tested (but on an old system with an old `dpkg`: 1.14.25) and `dpkg -L` inside the `postinst` worked fine. I suppose that means it's safe, then.

Comment: @muru To be clear, in the absence of explicit documentation I don't exactly feel comfortable trusting it, but I feel about the same level of odds with `dpkg -L` locking behavior during `postinst` remaining consistent and with the file path for the actual list file remaining the same, so might as well prefer the official interface.

Comment: @muru I've done more testing on a newer box too. It works there too, so it appears I was too paranoid but not meticulous enough when looking into it initially.

Comment: I tested this on a Debian 9 (dpkg 1.28.25) and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I read this [schematics](https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts), the files should be completely unpacked on postinst. So if you got a file `usr/share/foo/script.sh` in the package, you should be able to access this script at `/usr/share/foo/script.sh` :

[image: postinst debian mainainter schematic]

Comment: I am aware of that, I can access them from the filesystem, yes, but I want to run a script only over some files (following a naming-pattern), that are brought to the system with my package. The problem is to defer between the files that are already on the system and those I brought with my package. A solution/workaround would be to delete any file following the naming pattern first. Then I could be sure, that I run my script on the right files. But still - I think the most elegant way would be to get a file-list from the debian-package directly.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us, what your goal is with the script.

Comment: Okay, I thought that would lead too far from the actual problem (access only the files I brought with a package)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1: `dpkg --contents`

First of all, I do not think that the `dpkg -c` command would try to lock the system to list files in a `.deb`. It shouldn't. So in other words, it should work just fine in your `postinst` script.

### Solution 2: `dpkg-deb --contents`

However, if you look at the manual page, you'll notice that the `-c` (`--contents`) command line option is actually not supposed to be used with `dpkg` anymore. It is deprecated (it has been for 10 years or so).

They also mention the replacement:

```
dpkg-deb --contents <package-name>
```

Now, that will work too, except that you need to know which package was installed. i.e. to get the contents of a package, you need to know where the .deb is and the correct version and architecture (although the architecture may be much less of an issue).

In other words, this is not a good solution altogether.

### Solution 3: the list file

As mtraceur mentioned in his answer, you want to use the dpkg info file that lists the contents. Try:

```
less /var/lib/dpkg/info/YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME.list
```

That's the same list without the `ls -l`-like output making it a lot easier to parse for the files you're interested in.

### Solution 4: prepare that data at build time

What I would do, because I just don't like the other solutions, is a find at build time which generates a list with the file you are interested in. That becomes a form of configuration file you install say under `/usr/share/<package-name>/tag-files.list`.

Several reasons it is better:

- This file is very easy to parse, you read one line per file so you can use a simple `for` loop in your postinst script.
- The work of searching happens at build time: once (per build).
- The list can be verified if necessary, to make sure it is correct.